# Export Amazon API Gateway to Postman doesn't show requests (GET/POST/etc...)

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman

I recently started working with the Amazon API Gateway, and I tried the feature to export the requests. All of the videos I have seen showed that the exported request also included the methods. GET,POST,etc..

I tried different versions at postman, and looking at the export, I don't see the request. I just exporting the JSON and the Swagger files and got the same result.

Is there a switch I missed or something to get the methods to show up in the exported postman collection ?

```
    {
      "swagger": "2.0",
      "info": {
        "version": "2017-01-04T18:34:30Z",
        "title": "LambdaMicroservice"
      },
      "host": "mh4p5iqeyl.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
      "basePath": "/prod",
      "schemes": [
        "https"
      ],
      "paths": {
        "/wef_hello": {
          "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method": {
            "responses": {
              "200": {
                "description": "200 response"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, and maybe help someone else out.

I think I just needed to deploy the API so it is published, and now it generates the request properly.

Cheers